# how to prevent users from accessing inbox messages

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have been working on this custom inbox messaging. I am trying to setup so that only the inbox owner (user logged in) can view their messages. Right now anyone can type in a url such as `/users/1/messages/7` and view the message when it should only be readable by User wih id 1, not Users with ids 4, 5, 6, etc. I'm assuming I need to go in the messages model and add something like:

```
if inbox.recepient_id != @current_user.id
redirect_to :root
```

Any idea how to get this to work?

messages model:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
   attr_accessible :subject, :body, :sender_id, :recepient_id, :read_at,:sender_deleted,:recepient_deleted
   validates_presence_of :subject, :message => "Please enter message title"

   belongs_to :sender, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'sender_id'
   belongs_to :recepient, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => 'recepient_id'

   # marks a message as deleted by either the sender or the recepient, which ever the user that was passed is.
   # When both sender and recepient marks it deleted, it is destroyed.
   def mark_message_deleted(id,user_id)
      self.sender_deleted = true if self.sender_id == user_id
      self.recepient_deleted = true if self.recepient_id == user_id
      (self.sender_deleted && self.recepient_deleted) ? self.destroy : self.save!
   end
   # Read message and if it is read by recepient then mark it is read
   def readingmessage
      self.read_at ||= Time.now
      save
   end

  # Based on if a message has been read by it's recepient returns true or false.
  def read?
      self.read_at.nil? ? false : true
  end

  def self.received_by(user)
     where(:recepient_id => user.id)
  end

  def self.not_recepient_deleted
     where("recepient_deleted = ?", false)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

[Cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) is a gem for you. I use it in all my projects.

Comment: I have my own authorization and authentication. For my first app wanted to build from scratch as I will learn better that way.

Comment: just don't do that for your first app.

Answer (score 0):

One way i'd tackle this problem is to create a before_filter on your messages controller.

```
class Messages < ApplicationController
  before_filter :check_user_inbox

  def check_user_inbox
    if inbox.recepient_id != @current_user.id
      redirect_to :root
    end
  end

  ... 
end
```